# Cache Memory and How it is filled?

Tags: cpu-cache

If a computer has L1 L2 and L3 cache and 2 cores available.  When L1 on core 1 is filled.  Does the L1 in core 2 start trying to store data or does the L2 in core 1 start trying to store the data?

Comment: This is a question about computer architecture, not programming. [cs.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Each core uses its own cache.

Comment: L3 cache is shared by all cores, but L1 and L2 caches are private.